# Bounce Rate skewed by Conversion

Tags: google-analytics, landing-page, conversions, bounce-rate

We've got a landing page with a list of games and users generally either click the "Play Now" button (which goes to an external site) or they just leave. Currently, our bounce rate is 30%, but we can't differentiate between the users going to the conversion page or just leaving in our Bounce Rate %.

Is there a way to specify that a certain URL shouldn't affect bounce rate in Google Analytics?

Comment: Are you using event tracking on your links or are you using generic in-page analytics?

Comment: Just the in-page analytics

Comment: You can track analytics across two sites as if they were one, but that means adding extra code to the links between them. Would that be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to do it using In-Page analytics.  But, if you add [EventTracking](https://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#SettingUpEventTracking) to that particular action, you can set that particular click event to not be including in your BounceRate calculation.

Comment: Oh, where do I specify that the events aren't to be included in the Bounce Rate?

Comment: So, when the user clicks the button, you make a call to track the event (per the link in my answer) and the fifth parameter specifies whether or not to include the event in bounce rate calculations (true to not include and false to include.)